# Symfony2: How to use Twig templates as CSS files?

Tags: css, templates, symfony, twig

Somewhere in my  section of the base:html:twig there is something like

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('css/mystylesheet.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
% endblock %}
```

I want to define twig variables like {{ set mybgcolor='red' }} and use it to render mystylesheet.css.twig.

How can i render that one from within the base:html:twig?

Comment: I haven't tested it myself ... but there's a bundle available that registers a `"twig"` filter with assetic. A quick look at the code reveals that the filter renders files as twig templates. This might be what you're looking for: [TwigAsseticFilterBundle](https://github.com/igraal/twig-assetic-filter-bundle)

Comment: I did not understand your question. Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: I think his idea is to pass twig variables from a template to a stylesheet-template which then gets rendered on-the-fly. While using inline-CSS and changing the values in there might not be a good idea ...He could simply use the variable to include a different/additional stylesheet. I guess that would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @nifr is correct.  Using different/additional stylesheets is an option but requires more maintenance and the risk of errors.  Other options?